# delete in binary search tree C++ (tree won't update) and heap corruption

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, heap-corruption

I am trying to write a node deletion for a binary tree. These are my node and tree structures:

```
class node{
public:
    int value;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    ~node();
};

class tree{
public:
    node* root;
    ....
};
```

And this is the function I wrote:

```
void tree::del(node** r, int x){
if(*r)
{
    if((*r)->value==x)
    {
        if(!(*r)->left)
            *r= (*r)->right;
        else if(!(*r)->right)
            *r= (*r)->left;
        else 
        {
            int k= delMax((*r)->left);
            (*r)->value= k;
        }
    }
    else if((*r)->value > x)
    {
        node* k= (*r)->left;
        del(&k, x);
    }
    else
    {
        node* k= (*r)->right;
        del(&k, x);
    }
}}
```

My problem is that once I get to the desired element, the pointers change but then when the tree is rebuilt recursively it goes back to what it was originally and no element is deleted. I thought passing a pointer to the pointer would solve this but it didn't. `delMax` deletes the maximum element from the tree and it works correctly on its own.

Also, in the destructors for the last two classes, how should I place the deletes? because if I just put delete right; delete left; in `~node()` and delete root in `~tree()` I get an error that I'm corrupting the heap.

Thanks!

Comment: You might wanna read this: http://www.tech-faq.com/binary-tree-deleting-a-node.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I want to know what's wrong with my code because logically it works, but it doesn't even delete a leaf and not because it doesn't find it, but because it rebuilds the tree recursively.

Comment: Can you put in your delMax code?

Answer (score 0):

By making a local variable `k` and passing **its** address, the assignments through `*r` affect the local variable rather than any pointer *in* the tree.

As an aside, writing `node *&r` might save you several `&` and `*`s.